# How can i write a comment out block in netbeans of php by shortcut keys?

Tags: php, netbeans

I set a shortcut keys by : Tools->options->editors->code template ->create

[image: Netbeans settings]

I want get:

```
/** 
* @desc 
* @author myname
* @date 2018-12-01 10:00:00
*/
```

But get:

```
/** 
* @desc 
* @author author
* @date time
*/
```

the variable `${time}` not work?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the comment once per PHP file, it is easier to define it as comment within the file template (Tools --> Templates --> PHP --> PHP File --> [Open in editor].

There you can use f.e. the template vars

- ${user} for your user name
- ${date} for the current date
- ${time} for the current time.

Full list of usabel variables is defined in http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqTemplateVariables

Comment: thanks, bug not per PHP file, When I add a comment with a shortcut key(which I created by Tools->Options->editors->code template) to a function , it can automatically parse the variables in it.